ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : breakpoint not being hit
I have created an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project. I updated the program.cs with the desired code, however a breakpoint is not being hit, I can debug the code at entry of the program.cs.
proposalApi.MapGet("/proposals", () => {
    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(ProposalsDirectory);
        var files = dir.GetFiles("*.txt").Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
        var data = files.Select(x => new
        {
            index = int.Parse(new String(x.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray())),
            value = x
        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.index).Select(x => x.value).ToArray();

        return data.Count() == 0 ? Results.NotFound() : Results.Ok(data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ErrorDetails(ex);
    }
});

proposalApi.MapGet("/proposals/{fileName}", (int fileName) => {
    try
    {
        string content = File.ReadAllText(ProposalsDirectory + fileName);
        return Results.Ok(content);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ErrorDetails(ex);
    }
});

URLs attempted:
https://localhost:44312/proposals/proposals
https://localhost:44312/proposals/
Breakpoints:

Web api project code path (fiddle):
https://github.com/nitinjs/upworkify/tree/main/ProposalAPI.Core

Remove the .MapGroup("/proposals") from your example. When using MapGroup you create the group with common attributes then add the MapGet etc. to the group, not the base API endpoint where you want a path nested under the group. I would suggest scaling back to a single operation and see if that works before trying to write an entire API and trying to figure out why it doesn't work. 1 step at a time makes it easier to find and solve issues and not having to rewrite a bunch of code.

no luck, removed MapGroup, kept single MapGet https://github.com/nitinjs/upworkify/blob/main/ProposalAPI.Core/Program.cs

You mapped the entire proposalApi group to /proposals and then used the /proposals prefix again inside, resulting in a nested path like /proposals/proposals. This causes redundant paths, making the route inaccessible.

I modify the code and make it works in my side, please check it, thanks

Hi Bender, may I know if it is works for you ?

hi @Jason Pan, removed the redundant path, still it does not work, in browser page keeps in loading state https://localhost:44312/, https://localhost:44312/proposals I am using IIS express to debug. https://github.com/nitinjs/upworkify/blob/main/ProposalAPI.Core/Program.cs

Please use copy and paste my shared code, I have test it, it should be work.

https://i.sstatic.net/w4iIXNY8.png

@Bender Oh, I also find your repo can't works with IISExpress, I am using http.

@Bender You can try http first, and let me check why it not works in IISExpress, please be patient.

Change your code like below, it works in my side.
using ProposalAPI.Core;
using ProposalAPI.Core.Entities;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Net;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateSlimBuilder(args);

builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolverChain.Insert(0, AppJsonSerializerContext.Default);
});

var app = builder.Build();

string ProposalsDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + @"Content\Proposals\";

Func<Exception, IResult> ErrorDetails = (ex) => {
    return Results.Problem(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails()
    {
        Title = "Unexpected error occurred",
        Detail = ex.Message,
        Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
    });
};

var proposalApi = app.MapGroup("/proposals");
proposalApi.MapGet("/", () =>{
    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(ProposalsDirectory);
        var files = dir.GetFiles("*.txt").Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
        var data = files.Select(x => new
        {
            index = int.Parse(new String(x.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray())),
            value = x
        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.index).Select(x => x.value).ToArray();

        return data.Count() == 0 ? Results.NotFound() : Results.Ok(data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ErrorDetails(ex);
    }
});

proposalApi.MapGet("/{fileName}", (int fileName) => {
    try
    {
        string content = File.ReadAllText(ProposalsDirectory + fileName);
        return Results.Ok(content);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ErrorDetails(ex);
    }
});

proposalApi.MapPost("/", (string fileName) => {
    try
    {
        string content = File.ReadAllText(ProposalsDirectory + fileName);
        return Results.Ok(content);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ErrorDetails(ex);
    }
});

proposalApi.MapPut("/", (ModifyProposalModel model) => {
    try
    {
        string filePath = ProposalsDirectory + model.fileName;

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
        FileInfo fle = new FileInfo(filePath);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sr.Write(model.contents);
        sr.Flush();
        sr.Close();
        fs.Close();
        return Results.Ok<string>("Saved successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ErrorDetails(ex);
    }
});

proposalApi.MapDelete("/", (ModifyProposalModel model) => {
    try
    {
        File.Delete(ProposalsDirectory + model.fileName);
        return Results.Ok<string>("Deleted successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ErrorDetails(ex);
    }
});

app.Run();


with http it worked, kudos

Hi @Bender I found the reason why it not works when using IISExpress, please check the link, then we can find the correct start url here. https://i.sstatic.net/Z4BXz3sm.png
